# Variable in CSV File Contains Numbers But Imported as Character

Tags: r, csv, na

I have a variable in a dataset (CSV format) that consists only numbers but when the dataset is imported into R, it becomes a character variable. Any reasons why?

When I tried to coerce it as numeric, a lot of NAs are introduced.

```
> df1$Postal_Code<-as.numeric(df1$Postal_Code)  
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 

sum(is.na(df1$Postal_Code))
## [1] 2822

sum(is.na(as.numeric(df1$Postal_Code)))
## [1] 2837
```

Comment: It may be because there could be some elements that have non-numeric character.  Please check if there are `,` or other characters in the original data

Comment: When you coerce it to `numeric`, all the non-numeric elements also get converted to `NA`, thus you have an increase in NA.

Comment: Actually, yes, they are all numeric elements, so I was wondering why it get converted to characters in R. Could it be due to spaces? Like " "/"  "?

Comment: Check the elements that are converted to NA and you probably will discover what is wrong with your input: `df1$Postal_Code[!is.na(df1$Postal_Code) & is.na(as.numeric(df1$Postal_Code))]`

Comment: It could be anything, as you haven't provided any example, it is difficult to know

Comment: provide some reproducible data!

Comment: Alright thanks everyone!