# na.string in read.csv and ifelse function in dplyr::mutate

Tags: r, csv, dplyr, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I used 2 ways to import a data (in CSV format) into R. The first method does not have the `na.string` argument, while the second one has. I used the second one because some of the strings appeared as `""` instead of `NA` after the import, and that I want to standardise all missing values as `NA`.

```
data1<-read.csv("file.csv",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data2<-read.csv("file",stringsAsFactors=FALSE,na.string="")
```

I have 3 variables that are indicators. They give `"X"` for yes and `""`/`NA` for no. I tried to apply the following function to both `data1` and `data2` above.

```
df1<-data1%>%
     mutate(Indicator_Institution=ifelse(Indicator_A=="X",1,
                                  ifelse(Indicator_B=="X",2,
                                  ifelse(Indicator_C=="X",3,NA))))
df2<-data2%>%
     mutate(Indicator_Institution=ifelse(Indicator_A=="X",1,
                                  ifelse(Indicator_B=="X",2,
                                  ifelse(Indicator_C=="X",3,NA))))
```

`df1`'s `ifelse` function went through all the conditions, while `df2` only run the first condition. Any idea why? What difference does the argument `na.string=""` make?

Reproducible example:

```
    > dput(droplevels(head(data1)))
structure(list(Indicator_A = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "", ""), 
    Indicator_B = c("", "", "", "", "X", "X"), Indicator_C = c("", 
    "", "", "", "", "")), .Names = c("Indicator_A", "Indicator_B", 
"Indicator_C"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

> dput(droplevels(head(data2)))
structure(list(Indicator_A = c("X", "X", "X", "X", NA, NA), 
    Indicator_B = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "X", "X"), Indicator_C = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_)), .Names = c("Indicator_A", "Indicator_B", 
"Indicator_C"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please show a reproducible example.   Without an example, how willl others know what is going on in your data. The `na.string=""` will change all blanks to `NA`.  Based on your previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38449245/variable-in-csv-file-contains-numbers-but-imported-as-character) it seems that you want others to do guesswork.

Comment: Actually, I am not quite sure of how to show a reproducible example. The dataframe is obtained by importing the csv file and not created in R itself. Any suggestion on how I can improve my answer?

Comment: You can include a reproducible example with `dput`. i.e. `dput(droplevels(head(yourdata)))`  Also, it is `na.strings` and not `na.string`  It seems like your example have var1, var2, var3 as column names and in the code it is Indicator_A, Indicator_B, etc.

Comment: Hi, I have added the reproducible example. It seems that both `na.strings` and `na.string` give me the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that for the second case instead of blanks, we have `NA`.  If we use `==`, the NA values will remain as such.  To make those values as FALSE, use the `&` with `!is.na`

```
data2 %>% 
    mutate(Indicator_Institution = ifelse(Indicator_A == "X" & !is.na(Indicator_A), 1, 
                                   ifelse(Indicator_B=="X" & !is.na(Indicator_B), 2,
                                   ifelse(Indicator_C == "X" & !is.na(Indicator_C), 3, 
                  NA))))
```

---

Based on the example provided, this can be done easily with `which`

```
which(!is.na(data2), arr.ind=TRUE)[,2]
```